# What is the difference between spark's shuffle read and shuffle write?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to run a spark program which has huge amount of data. I am trying to optimize the spark program and working through spark UI and trying to reduce the Shuffle part.

There are couple of components mentioned, shuffle read and shuffle write. I can understand the difference based their terminology, but I would like to understand the exact meaning of them and which one of spark's shuffle read/write reduces the performance?

I have searched over the internet, but could not find solid in depth details about them, so wanted to see if any one can explain them here.

Comment: Number one optimization tip in Spark: try to reduce the number of shuffles.

Answer (score 12):

From the UI tooltip

Shuffle Read

> Total shuffle bytes and records read (includes both data read locally and data read from remote executors

Shuffle Write

> Bytes and records written to disk in order to be read by a shuffle in a future stage

Comment: so stage shuffle write data to next stage which shuffle read the data ,and the size of the data should equal?

Answer (score 2):

I've recently begun working with Spark. I have been looking for answers to the same sort of questions.

When the data from one stage is shuffled to a next stage through the network, the executor(s) that process the next stage pull the data from the first stage's process through TCP. I noticed the shuffle "write" and "read" metrics for each stage are displayed in the Spark UI for a particular job. A stage also potentially had an "input" size (eg. input from HDFS or hive table scan).

I noticed that the shuffle write size from one stage that fed into another stage did not match that stages shuffle read size. If I remember correctly, there are reducer-type operations that can be performed on the shuffle data prior to it being transferred to the next stage/executor as an optimization. Maybe this contributes to the difference in size and therefore the relevance of reporting both values.

Comment: Hi @Dranyar, I do not think it is just passing data to next stage, the shuffle occurs when you perform any group by kind of operations to get the data locality. I think it should be related to data movement over the network for specific operations.. What do you think.?

Comment: What do you mean by "it" in your statement: "I do not think it is just passing data to next stage"? I might be getting confused.

Also, I am unsure what you mean by "to get the data locality". It looks like the spark history UI indicates if a task happened to run local to the partition's location or not.